# Create Regular Expression for specified string in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsattributedstring, nsregularexpression

My `NSString` like below

`@"[o=uid=35=] hghk\u00c2\u00a0 [o=uid=30=] [o=uid=35=] cong."`

I need to create regular expression which search numeric values (e.g in first square brackets there is 35 in second there is 30 like this) in between square parenthesis. How could i achieve this task. Is there any alternate way to search numeric values in between square parenthesis? Please help me to short resolve from this. your help would be appreciable.

Comment: What have you tried? A pattern like "squareBracketOpening-equal-letter(only one?)-equal-letters-equal-number-equal-squareBracketClosing". Reading how works `NSRegularExpression` and its pattern should help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### http://regexpal.com/

use above link to check the expression

```
\b[0-9]+
```

to find all the integer values

```
([0-9])+
```

it works.

Answer (score 3):

Using NSRegularExpression,

```
NSString* strSource = @"[o=uid=35=] hghk\u00c2\u00a0 [o=uid=30=] [o=uid=35=] cong.";
NSError* errRegex = NULL;
NSRegularExpression* regex = [NSRegularExpression
    regularExpressionWithPattern:@"uid=([0-9]+)"
                         options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                           error:&errRegex];

NSUInteger countMatches = [regex numberOfMatchesInString:strSource
                                                 options:0
                                                   range:NSMakeRange(0, [strSource length])];
NSLog(@"Number of Matches: %ld", (unsigned long)countMatches);

[regex enumerateMatchesInString:strSource options:0
                          range:NSMakeRange(0, [strSource length])
                     usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult* match,
                                  NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL* stop) {

                             NSLog(@"Ranges: %ld", (unsigned long)[match numberOfRanges]);

                             NSString *matchFull = [strSource substringWithRange:[match range]];
                             NSLog(@"Match: %@", matchFull);

                             for (int i = 0; i < [match numberOfRanges]; i++) {
                                 NSLog(@"\tRange %i: %@", i, 
                                       [strSource substringWithRange:[match rangeAtIndex:i]]);
                             }
                     }];

if (errRegex) {
    NSLog(@"%@", errRegex);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can build a regular expression like this:

```
uid=([0-9]+)
```

This will find any numbers after "uid=" sequence in a string. The value of the number will be available in "match 1", since it is put in parentheses. You can try out this Regex interactively with http://rubular.com/.

Answer (score 1):

if you just want numeric value then you can try this

```
NSString *mainString = @"[o=uid=35=] hghk\u00c2\u00a0 [o=uid=30=] [o=uid=35=] cong.";
NSArray *arr = [mainString componentsSeparatedByString:@"="];
for(int i=0;i<arr.count;i++)
{
    NSString *newString = arr[i];
    NSCharacterSet* notDigits = [[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet];
    if ([newString rangeOfCharacterFromSet:notDigits].location == NSNotFound)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@",newString);
        // newString consists only of the digits 0 through 9
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my code,it works perfectly..we can check easily below array contains object(numbers between '[' and ']') or not without using any regex.

```
NSString *tmpTxt = @"[o=uid=35=] hghk\u00c2\u00a0 [o=uid=30=] [o=uid=35=] cong.";
    NSString*splittxt=tmpTxt;
    NSMutableArray*array=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for (int i=0; i<i+1; i++) {
        NSRange r1 = [splittxt rangeOfString:@"["];
        NSRange r2 = [splittxt rangeOfString:@"]"];
        NSRange rsub=NSMakeRange(r1.location + r1.length-1, r2.location - r1.location - r1.length+2);
        if (rsub.length >2 ){
            NSCharacterSet *AllowedChars = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"1234567890"] invertedSet];
            NSString*stringg=[splittxt substringWithRange:rsub];
            stringg = [[stringg componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:AllowedChars] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
            [array addObject:stringg];

            }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
        splittxt=[splittxt stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:rsub withString:@""];
    }

    NSLog(@"%@",array);
}
```

the array value is

```
(
    35,
    30,
    35
)
```